# How to make IIS use AppPool Identity to connect to SQL Server instead of NT Authority\IUSR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I've set up a Windows Server 2019 box with IIS, PHP 8 and SQL Drivers, and SQL Server 2019 Express.  I created a test PHP application and corresponding application pool, then set up a test database.  When trying to connect using sqlsrv_connect, I get the following error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

(There is more there in the SQL error but it's just the raw error array output and Stack Overflow doesn't like it.)

Now, I *believe* I have everything configured correctly to use the application pool identity instead of NT AUTHORITY\IUSR.  I copied the setup from another older (Server 2012) web server.  Screenshots of my setup:

[Anonymous Authentication using App pool identity in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIHsH.png)

[App pool identity added on database in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT0nY.png)

Am I missing a setting somewhere, or does Server 2019 handle application pool identities differently than server 2012?  I've tried following instructions like on this excellent SO page:

[IIS AppPool to SQL Server permissions (adding NT AUTHORITY\IUSR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231743/iis-apppool-to-sql-server-permissions-adding-nt-authority-iusr)

But it's like the server doesn't care that I've told it to use the application pool.

**UPDATE EDIT: MYSTERY SOLVED**

Apologies all, this was a case of extreme user error.  I put the "test" directory under wwwroot, ala c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.  I was accessing it as [www.domain.com/test](http://www.domain.com/test), when what I needed to do was set it to run as test.domain.com.  It was running under the wwwroot app pool (which in this case was using IUSR) because that is how I was accessing it.  Thank you everyone who helped me troubleshoot this!

Comment: Are you sure your app is running in the correct AppPool?

Comment: As far as I can tell, IIS says it's in the "test" AppPool:

https://i.imgur.com/TadMdAH.png

Comment: Is PHP even hosted in the App Pool process?  Or does it use CGI?

Comment: I'm using CGI, but PHP seems to be installed and running correctly.  I'm able to get phpinfo() to run - https://i.imgur.com/VRbuEmW.png

Comment: And what's the CGI "Imersonate User" setting?

Comment: It is set to "True" (the default).  I set it to "False" but that did not appear to make a difference just now, so I have set it back to false.

Comment: What you've shown in the second screenshot are database-level users. Have you also created IIS APPPOL\test at the service-level logins and mapped it to the database user?

Comment: I believe I've done so correctly - https://i.imgur.com/ix9D1mY.png

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Apologies all, this was a case of extreme user error.  I put the "test" directory under wwwroot, ala c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.  I was accessing it as www.domain.com/test, when what I needed to do was set it to run as test.domain.com.  It was running under the wwwroot app pool because that is how I was accessing it.  Thank you for everyone who helped me troubleshoot this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies all; this was a case of extreme user error.

I put the `test` directory under `wwwroot`, i.e., `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test`. I was accessing it as `www.domain.com/test`, when what I needed to do was set it to run as `test.domain.com`. It was running under the `wwwroot` application pool (which, in this case, was using `IUSR`) because that is how I was accessing it.

Thank you everyone who helped me troubleshoot this!